# Database in Phonegap Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am new to phonegap - blackberry. I am using Apache ANT, BBWP. I want to connect the database. I refer http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html but i cant understand fully. Can any one send me step by step to connect database and its operations. I have some more doubts, How to access access phone music player, and how to read read phone memory / SD card.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All is there in docs, nothing special other can serve you, otherwise they could have, as it's wiki! Dude, just try and believe in your self. Get some confidence..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this storage tutorial is about creating your own SQLLite like database. To connect to an existing database on a server, web services with JSON would be a way.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-quot-I-quot-would-call-a-web-service-from-a-WebWorks-App/td-p/519745/highlight/false